# Novel about climbing an immense city structure

Tags: story-identification

I read this scifi book in my early teens, I checked it out from the Odessa library. I for the life of me cannot recall the title and google has yielded nothing of what I can recall.

I felt like the title was something like "Forget the horizontal" or had something to do with Horizontal and or Vertical.

The story followed a male character traveling mostly on the outside and sometimes inside of a massive city structure that rose insanely high from the planets surface into the clouds. If I recall right so far up that most had never seen the surface of the planet. What other details I can recall are the description of the character sleeping in a tent/sleeping bag dangling off the side of the structure. The vehicle he rode was something similar to a motorcycle that shot hooks or piton from the wheels to adhere to the surface. I feel like the cover might have had an imagine depicting this.

It was an older book I think from the 70's maybe early 80's.

Comment: You'll find quite a few acropolis novels from that era. The better one are really good. The poor ones ... Well, lets just say that Ted S. was right.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Googling led me to the 1989 novel "Farewell Horizontal" by K. W. Jeter, but I have no personal experience with the book.  Description from [here](http://www.bookfever.com/book_listing/Jeter_KW_FAREWELL_HORIZONTAL_book_39168.html) seems to fit:

> Futuristic adventure story set in 'The Cylinder' - a massive structure
>   arising from earth

[image]

Comment: You're welcome, @CoffinKnail .  If that's it, please mark the answer as correct by clicking the grey check mark to the left of the answer.